# SQL Query to get count of status by other status for the same identifier

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table holding records that show the steps of a process:

```
    Status      | ModelID
-------------------------
    Set Remote  | 1
    Train       | 1
    Trained     | 1
    Enabled     | 1
    Set Local   | 2
    Train       | 2
    Trained     | 2
    Enabled     | 2
    Set Upload  | 3
    Train       | 3
    Trained     | 3
    Set Remote  | 4
    Train       | 4
    Trained     | 4
    Enabled     | 4
```

And I want to obtain the following result

```
     Status      | CountTrained | CountEnabled
-------------------------------------------------
     Set Remote  | 2            | 2
     Set Local   | 1            | 1
     Set Upload  | 1            | 0
```

I have tried the following query

```
    select 
       sum(case when status = 'Set Local' then 1 else 0 end),
       sum(case when status = 'Set Remote' then 1 else 0 end),
       sum(case when status = 'Set Upload' then 1 else 0 end)
    from TABLE
    inner join (select 
                   distinct ModelId,
                   status  as ModelStatus
                from TABLE
                where (status = 'Trained' or status = 'Enabled')) as Model
    on Model.ModelId = TABLE.ModelId
```

But this query doesn't return the results I need.

Any suggestion on how I can achieve the expected results?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want:

```
select modelid,
       max(case when status like 'Set %' then status end) as status,
       sum(case when status = 'Trained' then 1 else 0 end) as trained,
       sum(case when status = 'Enabled' then 1 else 0 end) as enabled
from t
group by modelid;
```

Comment: But i don't want the ModelId to be returned. I want to show 3 rows (one for each 'Set &' status) and 3 columns, 2 of those 3 columns are sums of the other 2 status

Comment: @rrruuuiii . . . Just remove `modelid` from the `select`, then.